# Web scraping with R: findElement doesn't recognise drop down menu

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape a [government database](https://www.odepa.gob.cl/estadisticas-del-sector/catastros-fruticolas) with multiple dropdown menus. Using RSelenium, I've managed to click on the button taking me to the interactive database ("Sistema de Catastros de superficie frutícola regional"), and I'm now trying to click on the drop-down menus (ex: region, year), but keep getting errors that there's NoSuchElement. I've tried multiple xpaths based on inspect element and the Selector Gadget chrome extension to no avail. It looks like each of the dropdown menus is a combobox.

If helpful, my end goal is to go through each of the regions, years, and crops; scraping the table generated by each one.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

rdriver = rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 9515L, chromever  = "106.0.5249.61")
obj = rdriver$client
obj$navigate("https://www.odepa.gob.cl/estadisticas-del-sector/catastros-fruticolas")

link = obj$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/p[2]/a')$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the button, a new tab appears.
You have to switch tabs with the help of

```
remDr$switchToWindow(remDr$getWindowHandles()[[2]])
```

Here is an example.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

Sys.sleep(15)

url <- "https://www.odepa.gob.cl/estadisticas-del-sector/catastros-fruticolas"
remDr$navigate(url)

Sys.sleep(15)

web_Obj_Button <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/p[2]/a')
web_Obj_Button$clickElement()

remDr$switchToWindow(remDr$getWindowHandles()[[2]])

web_Obj_Date <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#mat-select-value-3 > span > span")
web_Obj_Date$clickElement()

remDr$screenshot(TRUE)
```

[image]